# Terraform Azure function app from file upload

Tags: azure-functions, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to create a java Azure function app by uploading a zip file from the local file system . Below is the code. It is working as expected when ran from the windows 10 system. The same code doesn't seem to work when running from the ubuntu system, there was no error but the function app doesn't have any functions on azure portal. Terraform version is the same (Terraform v0.12.28) on both windows and ubuntu. Yet it doesn't seem to work on the Ubuntu.  below is the error message on the azure portal, function app
[image]
var.functionapp = "func_java.zip", zip file is in the same folder of main.tf

```
├── main.tf
├── tran_fun.zip
└── variables.tf


resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "appcode" {
    name = "functionapp.zip"
    storage_account_name = "${azurerm_storage_account.storage_account.name}"
    storage_container_name = "${azurerm_storage_container.storage_container_deployement.name}"
    type = "Block"
    source = "${var.functionapp}"
}


# // /***********************function app **********************************/
resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "spp_service_plan" {
  name                = "${local.app_serv_plan_name}"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg_creation.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg_creation.location
  kind                = "FunctionApp"

  sku {
    tier = "Dynamic"
    size = "Y1"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_function_app" "function_app" {
  name                      =  "${local.app_serv_name}" 
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg_creation.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg_creation.location
  app_service_plan_id       = azurerm_app_service_plan.spp_service_plan.id
  storage_connection_string = azurerm_storage_account.storage_account.primary_connection_string
  app_settings = {
    FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME = "java"
    FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION = "~3"
    APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY = azurerm_application_insights.app_insights.instrumentation_key
    APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING = "InstrumentationKey=${azurerm_application_insights.app_insights.instrumentation_key}"
    HANA_CREDENTIALS = var.hanaCredentials
    TENANT_ID = var.cptenantId
    HASH = "${filebase64sha256("${var.functionapp}")}"
    WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = "https://${azurerm_storage_account.storage_account.name}.blob.core.windows.net/${azurerm_storage_container.storage_container_deployement.name}/${azurerm_storage_blob.appcode.name}${data.azurerm_storage_account_sas.sas.sas}"
   
 }
}
```

Below is the error message from the function app console
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define the variable like this if the `.zip` file is in the same folder of `main.tf`.

```
variable "functionapp" {
    type = "string"
    default = "./func_java.zip"
}
```

It worked on my side.

[image]

For more details, you could read [this blog](https://adrianhall.github.io/typescript/2019/10/23/terraform-functions/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have referred the same blog. Its still not working when ran from Ubuntu, terraform apply runs with out error . But there are no functions in the function app.  In Azure portal, it  shows the error : "mscorlib:could not find file D:\home\site\wwwroot\host.json". Strangely, it works perfectly when ran from windows system.

Comment: Strange, I use the same code within ubuntu and windows without any issue. Perhaps, there is an issue in the func_java.zip? How did you get it? Can you validate it? Do you add the path like `default = "./func_java.zip"` including `./`?

Comment: Have you checked if the `host.json` included in the `func_java.zip` when you transfer or copy it on Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, I have included "./". This zip file was provided by a java developer. host file container below details .

Comment: {   "version": "2.0",    "extensionBundle": {     "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",     "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"   },   "aggregator": {     "batchSize": 1000,     "flushTimeout": "00:00:30"   },   "functionTimeout": "00:10:00",   "logging": {     "fileLoggingMode": "always",     "console": {"isEnabled": "true"     },     "logLevel": {"default": "Information","Host.Results": "Error","Function": "Information","Host.Aggregator": "Trace"     }   } }

Comment: What's the result of `tree` on Ubuntu?

Comment: added in the OP

Comment: Is there no other error or terraform error except the portal error `mscorlib:could not find file D:\home\site\wwwroot\host.json`? Are there any details when you clicking on that error notification?

Comment: There is no error with terraform apply  Added the error screenshot. Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 1 changed, 0 destroyed.
Releasing state lock. This may take a few moments...

Comment: Navigate to the Azure portal---app service (your function app )---console---run `ls` command, could you find the `host.json` file, also run `cat host.json` to check the content.

Comment: added in the OP. Thanks

Comment: The problem is that the host.json and other function apps file do not exist on that path `D:\home\site\wwwroot` when you deploy it with terraform.  What's the file of `tran_fun.zip`? Do you change the file name `func_java.zip`?

Comment: I suggest re-generating a `.zip` file to deploy to Azure function then we can narrow down the issue. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push#download-your-function-app-files

Comment: Sure, Let me check and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Nancy Xiong. This was issue with zip file. File got corrupted when i moved the file from windows to linux, .

Comment: glad it resolved. you could mark my reply that helps you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with zip file. Zip file got corrupted when moved from windows